# quiz app which is mutiple choice

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

I have a few activities where each one is a question and a last activity which will show the score to user. How do I do this? Can anyone teach me or give some example to use as reference?

How can I store the score for each question and then show the total score in the last activity? I don't know how to write the code for this. Can anyone teach me?

Comment: singleton with two vaiables correct answer,wrong answer. store all the correct question numbers in correct variable and wrong in wrong. and calculate based on that.
use sharedpreferences, bundle,intent,sqlite etc

Comment: how to use sharedpreferences. i not familiar to use sharedpreferences. how show me some example? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare any global varibale and increment it for all the correct answers.

When your quiz finished you can pass that varibale to the new activty that will show the result..

for ex--

int score;
QuizActivity.java

```
  Intent it = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, AnswersActivity.class);
  it.putIntExtra("Score",score);
  StartActivity(it);
```

AnswersActivty.java

```
Intent it = getIntent();
int score = it.getIntExtra("Score");
```

I hope this will help you...